# Plot scatter with categorical X without combining common X values

Tags: python, plotly, scatter

Hi I have a large dataset, and using add_trace I want to have a graph that shows a1,a1, and b1 as their x values, but default run of Scatter plot uses one a1 x for both y, how can I make the plot like this:
[The graph I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxXUs.png)

This is the code I have which gave me a different graph with common a1

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':('a1','a1', 'b1'), 'b': (1,2,3)})
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['a'], y=df['b']))
```

[This not the graph I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VI5yS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the dataframe index as the x values and column **a** as the text for the ticks

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly
import plotly.graph_objects as go
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':('a1','a1', 'b1'), 'b': (1,2,3)})
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df.index, y=df['b']))

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis = dict(
        tickmode = 'array',
        tickvals = df.index,
        ticktext = df["a"]
    )
)
```

[image]